# Iterating through a list with JQuery

Tags: jquery, struts

I retrieve my String from Struts using the following

```
$(document).ready(function( data ) 
{ 
   $('#contextsTextArea').val('<s:property value="myMessage"/>')
});
```

and it displays fine.
If my struts action returns a List of string instead how do I iterate through this list using JQuery?
This is my attempt but it does not display anything, Any idea what is wrong?

```
$('<s:property value="myMessage"/>').each(function (key, value) { 
    alert(value); 
});
```

Comment: How does it return a list?  What data type is it in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe best way to do this is to use [struts2-JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) and return JSON data from your action class.

Jquery already comes with a handy JSon parser mechanism and you can parse the returned List (converted in to JSON).